# Multiplication of matrices in R - problem of dimensions

Tags: r, matrix, multiplication, dimensions

I am trying to multiply to matrices in R:

I know this multiplication can be done, but I am getting an error. Any idea why?

```
> d1
     [,1]
[1,]   -3
[2,]    0
[3,]    3

> t1
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    2    2

> t1 * d1
Error in t1 * d1 : non-conformable arrays
```

Comment: I expect to got 0 from the multiplication

Comment: Try `t1 %*% d1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few details more starting from @ThomasIsCoding comment:

```
d1<-as.matrix(c(-3,0,3))
t1<-t(as.matrix(c(2,2,2)))


d1 %*% t1
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   -6   -6   -6
[2,]    0    0    0
[3,]    6    6    6
```

From the official CRAN documentation about matrix multiplication

> A * B is the matrix of element by element products and
>
> A %*% B is the matrix product.
>
> If x is a vector, then
>
> x %*% A %*% x is a quadratic form.

Link to the documenation [HERE](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Multiplication).